# Phonegap Android permissions, config.xml and plugins

Tags: android, permissions, cordova, config

I have a Phonegap app that I'm currently developing and testing for Android. Problem is, when I publish to device, the Android Manifest is full of permission requests that I did not ask for.

I have already figured out that the Phonegap Plugins (see [this docs page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) under "Add features") have something to do with it. If you install a plugin like Camera, then PhoneGap will automatically add the related permission to AndroidManifest. So I've uninstalled all Phonegap Plugins that I didn't need, and those permissions went away.

So far so good.

Trouble is, my Android Manifest (and a file called "android.json" in the project's /Plugins directory) still contain a number of unwanted features:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Since my app is about budgeting, a "Record video" permission would suggest to any sane user that this is an evil sneaky app trying to destroy their privacy.

How do I get rid of these feature requests? I already tried...

1. Adding `<preference name="permissions" value="none" />` to config.xml.
2. Uninstalling all related Phonegap Plugins. I even uninstalled a plugin AudioHandler that seems to have come preinstalled when I created the project.

Of course I can remove the stuff manually from AndroidManifest.xml before I publish my final version. But I would like a more structural solution, since I use "cordova run android" to test on device, and this overwrites all changes to AndroidManifest.xml and android.json.

Comment: Stranger still, the RECORD_VIDEO permission does not show up in the app's settings on device, but ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION do show up there.

Comment: you remove them from manifest file, that's the proper way to do it.  eclipse has a good interface for it, or intelli

Comment: maybe clean your project after uninstalling plugins too

Comment: A note for anyone using Phonegap BUILD: I tried the [preference name="permissions" value="none"] setting in my config.xml file and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you removed all plugins? (`use phonegap plugin list`) to see what plugins there are.

I Am not sure whether there is any difference, but I use

```
phonegap run android
```

in stead of

```
cordova run android
```

according to the docs the run command do both clean and build... so cleaning should be done.. (actually I use the -V command to get some extra debug info)

I also had a lot of troubles by the way, see: [Upgrade to phonegap 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923738/upgrade-to-phonegap-3-3-0)

And starting with an empty platforms folder is one of my tries.... than you should be sure it completely rebuild your manifest file....

**Edit 29-1-2014**

By the way, the best explanation of this CLI and phonegap 3.x issues can be found here: http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/